# Setting Jpgraph CACHE_DIR on a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, apache, jpgraph

How do you specify a CACHE_DIR for a Windows development machine running Apache? 
I tried the following with no luck:

```
define('CACHE_DIR','C:/root/public_html/mnc/jpgraph/cache/');
define('CACHE_DIR','C:\root\public_html\mnc\jpgraph\cache/');
define('CACHE_DIR','C:\root\public_html\mnc\jpgraph\cache\\');
```

The following is also set:

```
define('USE_CACHE',true);
define('READ_CACHE',true);
```

Graph creation is as follows:

```
$graph = new Graph(($tableWidth-2),($tableWidth/2),'auto',120);
...
$gdImgHandler = $graph->Stroke(_IMG_HANDLER);
// stream
$graphRendered = $filename;
$graph->img->Stream($graphRendered);
```

My img tag is as follows:

```
<img class="graphImg" src="<?php echo $graphRendered . '?' . uniqid()?>">
```

The cache folder has permissions set to *Full Control* for *Administrators*, *Users*, *SYSTEM*, and *Authenticated Users*.
My Apache root folder is `C:\root\public_html\`